# How many secondary-school students are working on achieving independent understanding?

Tags: education-research

If mathematicians and math teachers and textbooks in all cultures in all eras say that a certain theorem has been proved, then the reasonable layperson trusts them.

At the same time, a student who wants to understand mathematics works each day on trying to understand independently of such authorities why things in mathematics are as they are.

How widespread is knowledge of the point in the second paragraph above among those who have finished secondary-school mathematics? I.e. how many students know that pursuing independent understanding is the principal activity among those activities that constitute learning mathematics? **Has anyone attempted to measure this objectively?**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57941/discussion-on-question-by-michael-hardy-how-many-secondary-school-students-are-w). // Added to clarify:  I moved the comments to chat as they seemed centered around old versions of the question and as such obsolete. At the same time I did not want to 'completely' delete them as there seem to have been some lose ends that somebody may or may not want to pursue further.

Comment: Related meta post: https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/538/77

Comment: I would think this would not have been studied, because, although I do agree with the premise that striving for understanding first-hand rather than merely believing authorities' claims is a good thing, it is not clear to me that there is any sort of consensus about this in the first place, and many people would claim the opposite, etc. Indeed, it is my impression that very many people think math is about "following rules", even when the rules are inexplicable.

Comment: Googling on keywords like *university student attitudes mathematics* turns up a large amount of information, but it mostly seems to be about things like fear of mathematics, i.e., these are studies of the type of student population that has an inability to carry out mathematical algorithms.

Comment: My gut feeling (based on my experience teaching physics and a little math at a community college for 21 years) is that the students "working on achieving independent understanding" of math is less than 1% of this population. This provides two strong reasons why the data asked for in the question would be scarce. (1) Studies are mostly aimed at the ultimate goal of improving success, but this 1% is succeeding anyway. (2) You would need a big sample size.

Comment: @BenCrowell : You say the 1% is succeeding anyway, but don't mention the other 99%.

Comment: BEGIN QUOTE Indeed, it is my impression that very many people think math is about "following rules", even when the rules are inexplicable. END QUOTE That is obvious, and it ought to be similarly obvious that widespread belief in this falsehood is the inevitable effect of the way the secondary-school curriculum is designed. Even people who don't understand the easy-to-understand reasons why it has that effect should have realized by now that it does. And it seem as if it should be obvious to anyone who cares to know whose fault it is, but 99.99% of those to whom it$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$ought to be obvious will tell you your crazy if you state the obvious truth. Naked emperors exist. $\qquad$

Comment: @paulgarrett : "it is not clear to me that there is any sort of consensus about this [...] ". Indeed: It is not clear that there is any sort of consensus about the claim that mathematics is not a subject in which everything is already known. Probably numerous professors in other fields think it is a field in which everything is known. Should we defer to that opinion of ignorant people? "many people think math is about following [inexplicable] rules'"; therefore math professors should teach that? $\qquad$

Comment: Everybody please try to focus on the question at hand. If you want to discuss the subject, there is a chat-room already. One cannot move comments more than once; if the comment thread continues to grow there will be a comment-purge.